# Repository pattern and how to manage dependencies between entities

Tags: c#, database, repository, design-patterns

Let's say i have a database with employees and departments. I have created a simple object model to handle this :

```
class Employee
{
   decimal Salary;
   Department Department;
}

class Department
{     
    decimal TotalSalaries; //calculated as the sum of all employees salaries
                           //stored in database, not just a C# property
}
```

And..

```
class Employees
{
    void Create(Employee e);
    void Update(Employee e);    
    void Delete(Employee e);
    ...
}

class Departments
{
    ...
}
```

If i want to update an employee i would simply do :

```
Employee emp = Employees.GetById(1);
emp.Salary += 100; //salary increase
Employees.Update(emp);
```

**I'd like to have `TotalSalaries` of `Department` automatically recalculated everytime I update `Salary` of one of the employees**

I could do the following :

```
void Update(Employee e)
{
     ... //
     ... // sql stuff to update employee fields.

     Departments.ReCalculateTotalSalaries(e.Department.Id);
}
```

But if i do that, i think i break the Single Responsibility Principle. why should employee update method care about `Departments` ? This is a very simple example, but if I have lots of dependencies between entities, code could become very messy.

I have think about other ways to do that :

1) Create a service class for Employee : `EmployeeService`. Then in this class, define a method `Update()` to update an employee. That method will update employee AND recompute department total (by calling repositories methods of course).

```
void Update(Employee e)
{
     Employees.Update(e);
     Departments.ReCalculateTotalSalaries(e.Department.Id);
}
```

Problem : if I have lot of dependencies in my data model I would almost have to "double" my model layer (number of classes x2). Also : how can I be sure that controllers (or views) will always call the service methods, not the repository directly ?

---

2) in `Employees` repository have an event `OnSalaryChange()`, called from `Update()` method. The repository `Departments` will subscribe to it and will do the necessary when needed (in other words: call `ReCalculateTotalSalaries()`). Then, what belongs to `Departments` stay in `Departments`, `Employees` repository don't have to care about other entities.

Problem : it could becomes very hard to follow (by reading code or in debug mode) what happened when salary has changed (if there more than one subscribers). Also it could becomes a problem if subscribers need to be called in a particular sequence.

Comment: If you want to recalculate a field, why not use a trigger in your SQL or whatever DB engine you use? I also find you terminology really weird. Employees is supposed to be the interface of your repository?

Comment: Employees is a class. for simplicity i have put no interface. In real life it would be something like "EmployeeRepository : IRepository<Employee>". I dont want to use DB triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your reason for having a calculated field in your database (performance ?).
I try to avoid that case as much as possible.

*Cause update is not the only case* : if you delete an Employee, you have to recalculate also.

But this might be dangerous (for one reason, you work one day with a script in your database and forget to update manually your Department table after updating an employee's salary ?)

So

- you can create a trigger in your db (if you have code first, you can always use SMO to keep in "code" logic)
- you can create a db view
- you can have an Employees ICollection (or IList, or...) in your Department entity, and get a total salary as a "simple get property", which sums salaries of the list...

Comment: Yes its mostly for performance. I know about views and triggers they works very well and can be useful in some cases. But if you have lot of dependency between entities (to compute a you need b that need c and such) you end up with "views of views" and performance becomes a problem. Same for triggers that "trigger" another triggers and such. very hard to debug and maintenance can becomes nightmare if you have several databases. Solutions you give are nice for small DB or if calculated data is quite simple to compute.

Comment: Well I agree with you... but event that raise events that raise events and such... are just the same maintenance nightmare, or methods that shall be absolutly called in 4 methods to get your data clean are also complicated. Choice between performance and maintanability is always hard !

Answer (score 1):

In your case, yes, you break the single responsability principle.

To respect the principle, this line

```
Departements.ReCalculateTotalSalaries(e.Department.Id);
```

Should be

```
e.Department.ReCalculateTotalSalaries();
```

To do that, you must use a relation between your two entities in you database and in your DB schema.

**EDIT:** Note that ReCalculateTotalSalaries should modify the properties, but shouldn't save itself in the database. Therefore, because it doesn't touch the DB itself, it should be placed in your Departement entity and not in your DepartmentRepository

**EDIT2:** When you call `Employees.Update(yourEmployee)`, it will also save the yourEmployee.Department. That's the magic of this! No need to call one `Update()` for each entity!

Comment: Ok i understand. But then, who will call Departments.Update(e.Department)? (to update db rows). Also it needs to have a property "Employees" in e.Department, always filled and always up-to-date.

Comment: See my Edit2. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score -1):

Why not just constructor inject (or some other type) the other repository into the employee repository?

```
public EmployeeRepository(DepartmentRepository department){}
```

...then use _department for whatever you need. That's one clean way. You cannot get away from having to do complex interactions in your code.

...or to use an 'overseeing' repository that sort of combines the two - and has injected references for both - and does the Employee thing first, then calls the other? Maybe that's more like what you're thinking.
    MasterRepository(Employee employee, Department department)...
    SaveEmployee()
    {
        // do employee first, then...
        // call department
    }

hope this helps some.

EDIT: I wouldn't go with the events - for repository at least, there are reasons but the first is it doesn't  really feel good with Db and where data is about. First option I did not understand maybe similar to my Master repo.

Comment: As much as possible, I do not recommend to have dependencies between the repositories.